# Delphi VirtualStringTree OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

Hello please is there any VirtualStringTree version that contains these 2 Mouse Events :

`OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave` ?

Answer (score 4):

These events are easy enough to add if your string tree doesn't already support them.

```
  TMyImprovedVirtualStringTree = class(TSomeVirtualStringTree)
  private
    FOnMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnMouseLeave: TNotifyEvent;

    // Watch for MouseEnter and MouseLeave messages...
    procedure CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSEENTER;
    procedure CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage); message CM_MOUSELEAVE;
  protected
    // Provide MouseEnter() and MouseLeave() methods
    // for descendent controls to override if needed.
    procedure MouseEnter; virtual;
    procedure MouseLeave; virtual;
  published
    // Publish the events so they show in Delphi's object inspecter.
    property OnMouseEnter: TNotifyEvent read FOnMouseEnter write FOnMouseEnter;
    property OnMouseLeave: TNotifyEvent read FOnMouseLeave write FOnMouseLeave;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyImprovedVirtualStringTree }

procedure TMyImprovedVirtualStringTree.CMMouseEnter(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  MouseEnter;
end;

procedure TMyImprovedVirtualStringTree.CMMouseLeave(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  MouseLeave;
end;

procedure TMyImprovedVirtualStringTree.MouseEnter;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnMouseEnter) then
    FOnMouseEnter(Self);
end;

procedure TMyImprovedVirtualStringTree.MouseLeave;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnMouseLeave) then
    FOnMouseLeave(Self);
end;
```

Comment: I added calls to `inherited` to both of your message handlers. Without these you break the control because the underlying control already has handlers for these messages.